# How to make a webpage reload automatically when another session of the same website has done some work parallely?

Tags: java, jsp, messaging

I'm working with a project of patient queuing using JSP and Eclipse IDE. In it, I require a message to be conveyed between two different sessions of same website (i.e. the doctor's and compounder's homepage are alive).

As soon as the doctor finishes consulting a patient, a message is to be passed to the compounder's home page saying "To send new patient in".

I checked session creations and MVVM. But it doesn't satisfy me. Will anyone please help me out on this? I have tried an "auto refresh" inside JavaScript, but I ended up in an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very broad topic. You can go about it in several ways and using several technologies (message queues/brokers, websocket, dwr, etc).

This is similar to building a chat application so maybe search for that online (again another broad topic).

If you want something very simple (and most of the times inefficient - but that depends on your requirements) you can go about it this way:

1. Have a simple database behind your application (an application wide thread-safe queue should work too but a database gives you persistance in case something happens to the application, like a server crash);
2. once the doctor finishes the consultation, his page saves an entry to the database, a flag basically;
3. The compounder's page has an Ajax request that from time to time (say 10 sec) looks for the flag in the database;
4. if the flag is found it displays a message on the compounder's page to send the next patient and then resets the flag
5. repeat step 2.

Those are broad steps to build something simple. As I said, not the most efficient way. Search for how to build a chat and you'll find better ways since a requirement for chat applications is to be fast and scalable.

Comment: Sir, I'm very much thankful for this information.Right now ,I thought about the idea Auto Refresh and I searched for it.Found it as in [link](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_auto_refresh.htm).So I think to make it happen this way ..reload the compounders page using this and as and when it loads,I'll call a method that checks whether any flags have been set in the database table or not....if set then I'll print it on the screen...if not I'll do nothing...let me try ...if it does'nt work,I'll have to follow you...Any way,I'll keep in touch with you for further doubts...